# StencilJS imported styles does not work with hot reload

Tags: stenciljs

In my Stencil component the styles grew bigger and bigger and so I split it into several files. I use the scss `@import` to include all styles.
When I make changes in my base scss everything works fine, it triggers a build and the webpage gets updated with the new styles.
When I edit styles in my imported scss files it triggers a build but nothing happens on the webpage. Not even if I hit reload manually. I have to kill the `npm run start` process and rerun it for the updated styles to work.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's a known issue (see [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2635) and [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2741)).

There are some possible workarounds in those issues. A simple one that worked for me was to simply save the SCSS file with the `@import` (without any changes).